# Rails' structure.sql - what's best practice to solve painful merge conflicts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We suffer from an ongoing pain point in our Rails 4.x project.

We use `structure.sql` in the standard way as the base for our tests database. In development, we generate the file each time developers run `db:migrate`. When their migration is ready, they commit both `structure.sql` changes and the migration code itself.

However, we run into a problem when several developers deploy code with migrations to our staging environment. This is prone to causing merge conflicts in `structure.sql`, mainly because of new migrations written to the bottom of the file. NB The migrations themselves do not have to touch the same database tables for this to be a problem.

Is there any common and / or smart solution to this situation? We don't expect magic, but it causes more pain than we think it should.

*(We are going to ask our developers to be smarter about solving the merge conflict in the correct way, i.e. timestamps in the correct order, but it's not clear to us how much that will help in practice - we still believe that conflict in this file can be a problem moving forwards.)*

In edit: `schema.rb` doesn't support our requirements, this is about `structure.sql`.

Comment: Ok, the `sequel-rails` does the schema dumping without those lines if you would like to get some ideas from that. https://github.com/TalentBox/sequel-rails/blob/master/lib/sequel_rails/storage/postgres.rb

Comment: Doesn't every branch be worked upon independently ? Why would deploying code from one branch(being worked upon by say Developer A) cause conflicts when you deploy code from some other branch (being worked upon by say Developer B). Just have a mechanism to reverse the migrations each time you deploy these individual branches. Also, do you do `git checkout -f` of the branch to be deployed or `git pull` ?

Comment: Happy to explain some more. The problem is, branches are not deployed to separate environments, and we can't check just one branch each time and switch between them.

Our staging environment contains various branches at all times, some with new DB migrations.

Hat-tip to @reist for this, he couldn't comment because he's still building rep. :/

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a merge driver for git to resolve conflicts with structure.sql, so give it a try!

https://github.com/knu/git-merge-structure-sql

It will automatically merge the inevitable and most annoying types of conflicts, which include those with schema versions, database engine versions and AUTO_INCREMENT values (for older versions of Rails).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the major pain point of migrations. Remember that `structure.sql` is a simple sql representation of the current db state. If your developers all create and edit tables in parallel, you will need to merge them in a way or in another. Once you have them merged on machine, so you have an up to date DB, you can use `rake db:schema:dump` to create a "clean" new `structure.sql`, but it is useless if you did a good job while merging.

Anyway, a personal advice I can give you is to use the default ´schema.rb´ instead of the ´.sql´ format, it is way easier to merge if you have devs that prefer ruby itself over sql.

Comment: `schema.rb` is very limited, doesn't include any db views, functions or db specific things really, I never use it myself.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but it reflects more than addresses our concerns. And as Iceman pointed out, `schema.rb` doesn't fit our needs. :(

Comment: Sure, no problem. I was just sharing my experience about this. I doubt that you will obtain something you can consider the "right answer", because as I said, sooner or later you will have to merge your migrations. So you can find a way to avoid the conflicts most of the times, but it will be more an organization aspect, than a technical one